# Deriving equations of motion using Landau functional

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, lagrangian-formalism, superconductivity

I am having a difficult time understanding the derivation of the equation of motion using Ginsburg-Landau theory. Suppose $\mathcal{F}[\psi]$ is the free energy functional. Why is it that:

$$ 
\partial_t \psi = -\Gamma \dfrac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta \psi}.
$$

What is the intuition behind this relation? I know it has something to do with Hamiltonian mechanics - I just can't seem to put a finder on it intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

Hamiltonian dynamics plays no direct role behind Time-Dependent-Ginzburg-Landau theory. That equation of motion is meant to encode into a reaction-diffusion like  partial differential equation the coarse grained dynamics of a non-conserved  order parameter $\psi$. It is not the only possible dynamics, although it is probably the simplest.

In the case of conserved order parameter (i.e. when a continuity equation holds for $\psi$), other dynamics have been introduced. For example,the  Cahn-Hilliard equation:
$$
\frac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{t}}=\nabla^2 \dfrac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta \psi}.
$$
You may find a good introduction to the subject in the review paper by [Bray, A. J. (2002). Theory of phase-ordering kinetics. Advances in Physics, 51(2), 481-587](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s002200050508.pdf).

Comment: Thanks - that is definitely helpful. I see that this relation can be derived using the Continuity equation.